# How can I fix this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'?

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am attempting to add the values of cards that are pulled from a deck. I cannot figure out how to print the added values of the cards.

I have tried to change my module and import the module differently.

useofhand.py

```
def main():
    suits = ['Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs']
    ranks = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King'] 
    score = ScoredHand()
    thedeck = frenchdeck(ranks, suits)
```

createdeck.py

```
def frenchdeck(ranks, suits):
    decklist = []

    for rank in ranks:
        for suit in suits:
            decklist.append(ScoredCard(rank, suit, ranks, suits))

    return Deck(decklist)
```

scoredcard.py

```
class ScoredCard(Card):

    def __init__(self, rank, suit, rank_encoding = None, suit_encoding = None, score_encoding = None):

        super().__init__(rank, suit, rank_encoding, suit_encoding)

        self._score_encoding = score_encoding
```

card.py

```
def reversedict(dictionary):
    return {v:k for k, v in dictionary.items()}

class Card:

    def __init__(self, rank, suit, rank_encoding, suit_encoding):
        self.setrank(rank)
        self.setsuit(suit)
        self._rank_decoding = reversedict(rank_encoding)
        self._rank_encoding = rank_encoding
        self._suit_decoding = reversedict(suit_encoding)
        self._suit_encoding = suit_encoding
```

OUTPUT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\useofhand.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\useofhand.py", line 11, in main
    thedeck = frenchdeck(ranks, suits)
  File "C:\Users\MINE\Documents\cisc_120_files\lab4\createdeck.py", line 10, in frenchdeck
    decklist.append(ScoredCard(rank, suit, ranks, suits))
  File "C:\Users\MINE\Documents\cisc_120_files\lab4\scoredcard.py", line 7, in __init__
    super().__init__(rank, suit, rank_encoding, suit_encoding)
  File "C:\Users\MINE\Documents\cisc_120_files\lab4\card.py", line 9, in __init__
    self._rank_decoding = reversedict(rank_encoding)
  File "C:\Users\MINE\Documents\cisc_120_files\lab4\card.py", line 2, in reversedict
    return {v:k for k, v in dictionary.items()}
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: `ranks` is passed in as parameter `rank_encoding` but it is a `list` and hence has no attribute `items`.

Comment: What @a_guest said is the problem, but I'm not really clear on the solution cause it's not clear what you're trying to do. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: `ranks` and `suits` are supposed to be dictionaries that map the names to values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ranks` which is a list, and which becomes `rank_encoding` is where your code bugs. You are running :

```
self._rank_decoding = reversedict(rank_encoding)
```

which is doing :

```
return {v:k for k, v in rank_encoding.items()}
```

while :

```
rank_encoding = ranks = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
```

I think what you want to do is :

```
return rank_encoding.reverse()
```